# Location permission string in iOS Unity application

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, admob

Is there anyway I can find out which plugin/sdk is using the location APIs in iOS platforms?
Basically i am trying to get my app updated on the Apple store and I get a warning saying the following

ITMS-90683: Missing Purpose String in Info.plist - Your app's code references one or more APIs that access sensitive user data. The app's Info.plist file should contain a NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription key with a user-facing purpose string explaining clearly and completely why your app needs the data.tarting Spring 2019, all apps submitted to the App Store that access user data are required to include a purpose string. If you're using external libraries or SDKs, they may reference APIs that require a purpose string. While your app might not use these APIs, a purpose string is still required. You can contact the developer of the library or SDK and request they release a version of their code that doesn't contain the APIs. Learn more (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/core_app/protecting_the_user_s_privacy).

I really don't feel comfortable adding a string without knowing what it does in my app